# R or another robust Ruby math lib on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, r, math, heroku

Can [R Project](http://www.r-project.org/) be coaxed to work on Heroku Cedar?  Or is there another robust math library that can / should be used on Heroku (Cedar)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is for a specific project, the beginning of the README should be what you are looking for:

https://github.com/noahhl/rookonheroku

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the [heroku-buildpack-r](https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r) for running R on Heroku.